How to overcome Limitations of SpringAI and make it better
I am exploring Spring AI to integrate AI capabilities into my Spring Boot projects, but I’ve encountered several challenges. One of the main issues is related to the use of Google's Gemini, which is a free and great performing LLM Model. Unfortunately, Spring AI only provides access to Gemini through Google Vertex AI and the Google Cloud CLI, making the process cumbersome and eliminating the "free" advantage as developers have to add their credit card details while setting up a Vertex AI account. Other frameworks allow the use of direct Gemini APIs eliminating this issue.
Spring AI supports access to Gemini exclusively via Google's Vertex AI only, requiring developers to manage authentication through Google Cloud. This approach complicates the development process compared to other frameworks like Django, which supports direct integration with standalone Gemini APIs.
This restriction becomes a significant drawback for Spring AI, forcing developers to either abandon the framework or undertake complex manual configurations. A similar limitation applies to other LLMs, such as Llama and Cohere. Spring AI mandates their integration through intermediaries like AWS Bedrock, preventing direct API usage and adding unnecessary complexity to the workflow.
Now i am unable to integrate AI Services into my spring project for free trial
How do we solve this or Request Authors at Spring to improve on This?

you can use ollama on your local system with spring boot application. and as for Google gemini integration you can go to spring ai github project and start discussion about it you will get answer very quickly because community is very active now.

Thanks a lott for that suggestion ... will definitely try that
